# Facebook App is not returning to my app when I try to login into Facebook App

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I have made an app that is integrated with Facebook and it is working perfectly BUT I have a problem.

Test A - Works perfect

1. Login in the Facebook App;
2. Open my app;
3. Call Facebook Login;

Test B - Problem

1. **Logout** in the Facebook App;
2. Open my app;
3. Call Facebook Login;
4. Facebook App ask me to login;
5. Login success - but facebook does not return to my app;

Can anyone help me?

Obs: I am using the Facebook SDK 3.0 and iOS6 beta 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, make sure you override the `- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application openURL:(NSURL*)url sourceApplication:(NSString*)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` method as is detailed in the FB docs:

That is, in your App Delegate class, you should have the following:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application openURL:(NSURL*)url sourceApplication:(NSString*)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    // Do stuff here...
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't implemented the URL scheme for your app. When you register your app with facebook, it provides a facebookid. Something like fb1023098123. You have to implement this id as a url scheme in your app.

When facebook logs in via an app reference, it then calls the facebook id url to launch the application on the device. Without it, the device doesn't know what application to launch when facebook calls the hyperlink.